# Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead. GradientBostingRegressor

Tags: python-3.x

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingRegressor
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mapie.regression import MapieQuantileRegressor

Model = GradientBoostingRegressor(
 n_estimators = 500,
 max_depth = 4,
 min_samples_split = 5,
 learning_rate = 0.01,
 loss = "quantile")

X, y = make_regression(n_samples=5000, n_features=1, noise=20, random_state=59)

X = dict(enumerate(X.flatten(), 1))
y = dict(enumerate(y.flatten(), 1))

df = pd.DataFrame({'X':X, 'y':y})

X_train, X_tmp,  y_train, y_tmp  = train_test_split(df.X, df.y, test_size=2000, random_state=42)
X_calib, X_test, y_calib, y_test = train_test_split(X_tmp, y_tmp, test_size=1000, random_state=42)

alpha = 0.1
mapie = MapieQuantileRegressor(estimator=Model, cv="split", alpha=alpha)
mapie.fit(X_train, y_train, X_calib=X_calib, y_calib=y_calib)
y_pred, y_pis = mapie.predict(X_test)

predictions = y_test.to_frame()
predictions.columns = ['y_true']
predictions["point prediction"] = y_pred
predictions["lower"] = y_pis.reshape(-1,2)[:,0]
predictions["upper"] = y_pis.reshape(-1,2)[:,1]
predictions
```

Attempts to obtain confidence intervals for the GradientBoostingRegressor model. I use the MAPIE library for this purpose.
When I try to compile the program I get the error  Unfortunately, I cannot fix this error myself. Please help me.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-2ca3f38dea46> in <cell line: 31>()
     29 alpha = 0.1
     30 mapie = MapieQuantileRegressor(estimator=Model, cv="split", alpha=alpha)
---> 31 mapie.fit(X_train, y_train, X_calib=X_calib, y_calib=y_calib)
     32 y_pred, y_pis = mapie.predict(X_test)
     33 

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, estimator, input_name)
    900             # If input is 1D raise error
    901             if array.ndim == 1:
--> 902                 raise ValueError(
    903                     "Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:\narray={}.\n"
    904                     "Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if "

ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[ 0.5914918 -1.9605857  1.3109057 ... -1.1724522 -1.8717328 -2.839449 ].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `df.X` or `df['X']` returns the X column data as a *series*, which is 1D. The model's `.fit()` needs the features as a 2D matrix shaped `n_samples x n_columns`.

You could read `X` out as a 2D structure using `df[['X']]` (or `df.X.to_frame()`):

```
X_train, X_tmp,  y_train, y_tmp  = train_test_split(
    df[['X']], df.y, test_size=2000, random_state=42
)
```

Or alternatively, keep your code as-is using `df.X`, but add a reshaping operation to all `X` variables to make them 2D: `X_train = X_train.reshape(-1, 1)`, same for `X_tmp`, `X_calib`, `X_test`.

After doing any of the above, `print(X_train.shape)` will be a 2D column vector `(3000, 1)` rather than the 1D `(3000,)`